# Exporting file from Google Dataproc Job

Tags: scala, google-cloud-dataproc, google-bucket, scala-spark

I'm trying to export a png file using google bucket path but when I execute the job it tells me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: gs://...//test.png
```

I used the same code in local mode and it works. Here it is:

```
val test = LinePlot.series(data, "WSSSE elbow", HSL(210, 100, 56))
.xAxis()
.yAxis()
.frame()
.xLabel("Number of cluster")
.yLabel("WSSSE")
.render()

val image = test.asBufferedImage
val file = new File("gs://.../test.png")
ImageIO.write(image, "png", file)
```